# Fewer Columns in INSERT than VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a stored procedure and have declared a table as part of the code. I get an error

> There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause

Here's my code:

```
DECLARE @FullTaskList TABLE (fval INT)

INSERT INTO @FullTaskList(fval) 
VALUES ( (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) )
```

I would be very grateful if you can help me.

Answer (score 7):

You just have too many parentheses:

```
DECLARE @FullTaskList TABLE ( fval INT )
INSERT INTO @FullTaskList ( fval )
    VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
```

Your syntax is interpreted as `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`, which is five values in one row, rather than five rows with one value.

Answer (score 5):

remove extra parenthesis because that indicate you are going to insert 5 columns instead 5 rows

```
DECLARE @FullTaskList TABLE ( fval INT )
INSERT INTO @FullTaskList ( fval ) 
VALUES  (1), (2), (3), (4), (5) ;
```

Comment: Thanks! Never even realised.